# Upper & Lower angular limits on Y and Z axes

Tags: unity, rotation, joints

**My Task:**
I'm trying to replicate [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBgG_VSP7f8) project. I'm using unity as my physics engine. 
Currently I'm still learning how to work with the different joints unity has to offer. The type of movement I'm looking for is where a body is connected to only one other body and its relative movement can be limited based on angles on different axes.

**My Problem:** I'm using [Configurable joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ConfigurableJoint.html) for my movement restrictions. The *Low Angular X Limit* and *High Angular X Limit* does exactly what I'm looking for since it can have a different uppper and lower rotation limit. Looking at the documentation, it seems that this can only be done on the X axis. The Y and Z axes only have a *Angular Y Limit* or *Angular Z Limit* which set the upper as the opposite of the lower limit.

**My Question:** Is it possible for the Y and Z axes to have the same lower-upper limit system that the X axis has? Is the use of configurable joint good for this task?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It sounds like you could get the behaviour you want by chaining two joints: one on the x axis, and one twisted 90 degrees so that its x is your y. Or a single configurable joint where you've simply rotated its initial/neutral y to be equidistant between your high and low limits, so that you can express the limit symmetrically about this neutral pose..How have you tried solving your problem so far?

Comment: Currently, I don't have a direction for a solution. In your first solution, do you mean to twist the joint itself? How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I used the method @DMGregory suggested and rotated the joint before setting the limits. Since the joint limits rotation and also cannot be disabled I created a script that rotates and then adds the joint.

```
public class ConfigJoint : MonoBehaviour {

    private ConfigurableJoint joint;

    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody connectedBody;

    [Header("Angular X Limits")]

    [SerializeField, Range(-180, 0)]
    private float xLower;
    [SerializeField, Range(0, 180)]
    private float xUpper;


    [Header("Angular Y Limits")]
    [SerializeField, Range(-180, 0)]
    private float yLower;
    [SerializeField, Range(0, 180)]
    private float yUpper;

    [Header("Angular Z Limits")]
    [SerializeField, Range(-180, 0)]
    private float zLower;    
    [SerializeField, Range(0, 180)]
    private float zUpper;

    [Header("Anchors")]
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 anchor;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 connectedAnchor;

    void Start () {                

        Rotate(); // Rotate to the rotation that matches the wanted limits

        joint = gameObject.AddComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();  // Adds a configurable joint

        LockMotion();   // Sets all movement to Locked
        LimitRotation();    // Sets all angular movement to Limited

        SetAnchors();   // Sets the anchors to the wanted anchors

        SetAngularLimits();  // Sets the limits for the joint
    }

    private void Rotate()
    {
        // The mid point between the upper and lower limit
        float xMid = (xUpper + xLower) / 2;
        float yMid = (yUpper + yLower) / 2;
        float zMid = (zUpper + zLower) / 2;

        //Debug.Log("Setting rotation: " + new Vector3(xMid, yMid, zMid));
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xMid, yMid, zMid);        
    }


    private void SetAngularLimits()
    {        
        // The value that each angular limit needs to be to create the effect of an upper and lower limit
        float xAbsAvg = (xUpper - yLower) / 2;
        float yAbsAvg = (yUpper - yLower) / 2;
        float zAbsAvg = (zUpper - zLower) / 2;

        SoftJointLimit sjl = new SoftJointLimit();

        sjl.limit = xAbsAvg;
        joint.highAngularXLimit = sjl;

        sjl.limit = -xAbsAvg;
        joint.lowAngularXLimit = sjl;

        sjl.limit = yAbsAvg;
        joint.angularYLimit = sjl;

        sjl.limit = zAbsAvg;
        joint.angularZLimit = sjl;


    }

    private void SetAnchors()
    {
        joint.connectedBody = connectedBody;
        joint.anchor = anchor;
        joint.connectedAnchor = anchor;
    }

    private void LockMotion()
    {
        // Body parts should not move. They can only rotate
        joint.xMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;
        joint.yMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;
        joint.zMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Locked;
    }

    private void LimitRotation()
    {
        joint.angularXMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
        joint.angularYMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
        joint.angularZMotion = ConfigurableJointMotion.Limited;
    }    
}
```

**How to use:**
Add this to the component you would add the configurable joint to. All parameters are pretty self-explanatory or parallel to those in regular joints.

Comment: It seems now like this script has some bugs. It isn't working, when fixed I'll edit the answer.